# Statement's odd behaviour

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, windows-xp

I've had an odd behaviour last week with a if condition and I would thank any one who has any idea of what had happened. Although I've found a workarroud I don't like to be in the shadows.

Let me explain.

***Scenario 0*** (this was working before everything exploded)

**Langauge**: Visual Basic
**Net Fwk**: 3.5
**Client**: XP (x86) machine (Winforms)
**Database**: Access on a Shared Folder of a Win Server 2008 (don't know if x86 or x64)
**DB Provider**: Jet OleBD
**Office**: 2007 x86

Why Access?
Low cost, MS Access available for the user and it fits all I needed.

And one day Win7 appeared:

***Scenario 1*** (here is when everything stopped working)

**Langauge**: Visual Basic
**Net Fwk**: 3.5
**Client**: Win 7 (x64) machine (Winforms)
**Database**: Access on a Shared Folder of a Win Server 2008 (don't know if x86 or x64)
**DB Provider**: ACE OleBD x86
**Office**: 2010 x86

In this new scenario, the application started to work wrong.

And the odissey begins.

First I tested the application on my development machine. The scenario was similar to Scenario 0 so everithing worked ok.

Then I started a Win7 test machine and tried to find if I could get where the problem was:

***Scenario 2***

**Langauge**: Visual Basic
**Net Fwk**: 3.5
**Client**: Win 7 (x64) machine (Winforms)
**Database**: Access on a Local Folder
**DB Provider**: ACE OleBD x86
**Office**: 2010 x86

I Test the application and everything works fine.

After crying like a baby for 2 or 3 minutes, I decided to connect to my customer's server through internet using my Win7 test machine.

***Scenario 3***

**Langauge**: Visual Basic
**Net Fwk**: 3.5
**Client**: Win 7 (x64) machine (Winforms)
**Database**: Access on a Shared Folder of a Win Server 2008 (don't know if x86 or x64)
**DB Provider**: ACE OleBD x86
**Office**: 2010 x86

Amazed the same application I run against my local DB, fails against the remote db (just changed the connection string in the config file).

I've started adding debug statement to the application and tested one and again so I could find why it doesn't work as spected.

Finally, I found that the statement

```
If FinalDate.Subtract(StartingDate).TotalDays + 1 = 7 Then
```

returns always **False** in Scenario 1 and 3 (ALWAYS!). And **True** or **False** in Scenario 0 and 2.

I've damned Thor and tested this change to the statement

```
Dim totalDays As Integer = CInt(FinalDate.Subtract(StartingDate).TotalDays)
If totalDays + 1 = 7 Then
```

As you imagine, this works fine.

But the question is "Why?".

WHY????!!!!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx):

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
>   and fractional days.

So if you only need whole-days then it is safest to cast to Integer anyway, and avoid any possible concerns about the time-part.